# Unable to compile C# 8 using .NET Core 3, Preview 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, c#-8.0

I am currently using **.NET Core 3, Preview 4**, and **Visual Studio 2019, Version 16.0.2**.

Here are the contents of my `.csproj` file for my .NET Core project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

As an experiment, I copied some code taken from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) into my project:

```
public static string RockPaperScissors(string first, string second)
=> (first, second) switch
{
    ("rock", "paper") => "rock is covered by paper. Paper wins.",
    ("rock", "scissors") => "rock breaks scissors. Rock wins.",
    ("paper", "rock") => "paper covers rock. Paper wins.",
    ("paper", "scissors") => "paper is cut by scissors. Scissors wins.",
    ("scissors", "rock") => "scissors is broken by rock. Rock wins.",
    ("scissors", "paper") => "scissors cuts paper. Scissors wins.",
    (_, _) => "tie"
};
```

However, it won't compile:

[image]

As you can see, the compiler displays the error message "Unexpected token".

What should I do to be able to use C# 8 language features in my .NET Core project?

Comment: what happens if you add `<NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions> inside the PropertyGroup in your .csproj?

Comment: @mcalex Unfortunately, your suggestion did not work -- I see the exact same error message. :-(

Comment: @mcalex note that in VS 16.1 the NullableContextOptions property was renamed to Nullable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disabled ReSharper, and the problem disappeared.